# prevent an infinite loop in a production system(Js Code Test question)

Tags: javascript

Please understand the following program:

```js
function recur(n, cur) {
  if (!cur) {
    cur = 0;
  }
  if (n < 2) {
    throw new Error('Invalid input');
  }
  if (n === 2) {
    return 1 / n + cur;
  }
  return recur(n - 1, cur + 1 / (n * (n - 1)));
}
```

To prevent an infinite loop in a production system. Write a program doing the same
calculation without recursion. Please be reminded that a while loop is also considered
not good in a production system.

I don't quite understand what the original CODE is supposed to do  :(

Comment: correct me if i'm wrong, but your `recur` can't fall into infinite loop.

Comment: Assuming that your first argument (`n`) is a number, any `n < 2` will throw the error, and any `n > 2` will eventually get to 2, since the recursive function is called with `n - 1` as the first argument. Therefore, it terminates. So, is that your question (understanding why it terminates), or are you seeking help to rewrite it without recursion?

Comment: yes, i am seeking help to rewrite it without recursion :)

Comment: @GerardoFurtado `n = Infinity` is a special case, which would _not_ eventually get to 2 but result in an infinite loop.

Comment: @OskarGrosser I know that in JS typeof Infinity gives "number", but mathematically speaking Infinity is not a number... But yes, it should be *"Assuming that your first argument (n) is a number, but not `Infinity` or `NaN`"*, because despite the name `NaN` is also a number...

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Absolutely! I just thought since this is a _test_ question asking "to prevent an _infinite_ loop" that we should look at corner cases like Infinity. NaN is taken care of by: `if (!cur) cur = 0;`

Comment: @OskarGrosser I'm afraid it's not taken care of, that checks for `cur`, but we're talking about `n`.

Answer (score 2):

here is your function without recursive.

```js
function nonRecur(n, cur) {
    if (!cur) {
        cur = 0;
    }
    if (n < 2) {
        throw new Error('Invalid input');
    }
    for (; n > 1; --n){
        if (n === 2) {
            cur = 1 / n + cur;
            break;
        }
        cur = cur + 1 / (n * (n - 1));
    }
    return cur
}
```

Comment: Oic, you're great

Answer (score 0):

you can try below code for the same

```
function recur(n, cur) {
 if (!cur) {
  cur = 0;
 }
 if (n < 2) {
  throw new Error('Invalid input');
 }
 for(var i = n; i > 2; i--){
    cur = cur+1/(i * (i -1));
 }
 return 1 / i + cur;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Python solution for this

```
# Cur default value is 0, if it is not pass.

def recurFunction(n,cur=0):
    if n < 2:
        # print("Error: Invalid input")
        return ValueError("Invalid input")

    # Decreasing the value of n by 1 till n become 2
    for i in range(n,1,-1):
        if i == 2:
            return 1/i+cur
        else:
            cur = cur+1/(i * (i -1))
```

Answer (score -1):

In python, we can convert this recursion problem into iteration by following snippet.  [image: Please check this code image]. Also there is a website where you visually check the recursion process [Visualise Recursion process](https://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=display). I hope you will find my solution perfect.